# Как правильно сохранить данные в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Сохраняю на базу, все нормально сохраняет, но при обновлении браузера сохраняет еще раз?

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['save'])) {
    $titles      = $_GET['title'];
    $description = $_GET['description'];
    $img_path    = $_GET['img_path'];
    $date        = $_GET['date'];
    $content     = $_GET['content'];
    $query       = "Insert Into news (title,description,img_path,date,content) Values ('$titles','$description','$img_path','$date','$content')";
    $result      = mysql_query($query);
}

?>

<form action="" method="get">
    <p>
        <label>название:</label>
        <input type="text" name="titles" id="title" class="auto-focus"
        />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Описание:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description"
        class="auto-hint" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Путь к Images:</label>
        <input name="img_path" type="file" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Дата :</label>
        <input name="date" type="datetime-local" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Содержимое:</label>
        <textarea cols="80" rows="4" id="message" name="content"
        class="auto-hint"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="save">Сохранить</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Мде... Значит, после отправки данных из формы, вы нажимаете F5, а браузер недоверчиво спрашивает, мол: "Что? Еще раз отправить данные?". Вы по честному соглашаетесь и потом долго чешите затылок - почему же опять добавилась запись в базу? Неужели всё так и происходит?

Comment: да все и так происходит

Comment: @Deonis на заметку, Opera не спрашивает о повторной отправке формы!!!

Comment: Это конечно не ответ, но просто для размышления - попробуйте начать изучать и разрабатывать AJAX. Там эта проблема сама собой исчезает.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно перенаправлять на другую страницу, например с сообщением "молодец, вы все хорошо сделали :)

```
//тут код сохранения, который я не стал копировать 
header('Location: ' . $yourUrl);//Отправляем заголовки браузеры, чтобы он открыл $yourUrl
exit();//дальше ничего делать ненужно, браузер сделает все за вас :)
```

~~~

И вообще, когда что-то сохраняете из форм, используйте метод POST, т.е. у вас в форме должно быть

```
<form action="<ваш урл>" method="POST" ...>
```

а в коде:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST']) {
    сохраняем данные
    header(....
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зря заминусовали [[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan) . Просто тему не раскрыл, а так есть смысл в этом решении. Если, к примеру поле **`title`** сделать уникальным (UNIQUE KEY), то запрос можно построить таким образом:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`title`, `description`) VALUES ('$title','$description')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `description` = '$description';
```

Comment: Решение бессмысленное и беспощадное, таких ситуаций не должно быть, когда вам при добавлении данных через интерфейс надо надо делать insert duplicate update, там должно быть "добавить" и "изменить". Если юзер хочет изменить данные - это должно происходить им осознанно, а не на основе каких-то не явных факторов.

Comment: Ну, по поводу "осознанности" - то исходя из вопроса, можно сделать вывод, что "не явные факторы" вполне имеют место быть )) М я не говорил, что это лучший способ, а отметил, что и такой способ может быть.